# Can't get ng2-charts to work in Angular 4 with shared components

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

angular 4.0.0 
angular-cli 1.2.1 
ng2-charts 1.6.0

I can get ng2-charts to work in the normal way, but I can't get it to work in "shared" components.

I have a shared-components.module which gets imported by app.module. If I try to use ng-charts in one of the components in shared-components I get a

**"Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'"**

error, among others.

Here's my very basic setup:

**app.module**

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
import { RootLevelComponent } from './components/root-level-component.component;
import { SharedComponents } from './modules/shared/shared-components/shared-components.module';

declarations: [
  RootLevelComponent
],
imports: [
  SharedComponents
  ChartsModule
],
```

**shared-components.module**

```
import { SharedComponent } from '../components/shared-component.component';

declarations: [
  SharedComponent
],
exports: [
  SharedComponent
]
```

This works fine if as long as it's in my root level component template:

**root-level-component.html**

```
<canvas baseChart
  [data]="myData"
  [labels]="myLabels"
  [chartType]="'pie'"
  (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
  (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

The same setup does not work in my shared component template:

**shared-component.html**

```
<canvas baseChart
  [data]="myData"
  [labels]="myLabels"
  [chartType]="'pie'"
  (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
  (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

I get the "Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'" error when I try to use it in my shared-component.

Comment: have you added `SharedComponentsModule` in your `AppModule`?

Comment: I have. I have a number of shared modules and shared components that all play nice together. I just can't get ng2-charts to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ChartsModule` in your `shared-components.module` imports:

```
imports: [
  ChartsModule
],
```